# reading php ajax responce into phonegap

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I am creating app in phonegap. I just try to catch the response from server to my application for further process. My Ajax call get succeed but I have not get responce in proper format.
I use: Phonegap Desktop App, Phonegap Developer App on Android Phone.

#### My Server Side Code:

```
public function signup()
{
    echo "here is sign up";
}
```

#### MY Ajax Function code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#signup").click(function(){
    alert("ajax");
    var password=$("#password").val();
    alert("before="+password); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.companyworks.epizy.com/DMB/index.php/Welcome/signup",
        data: "pass="+password,
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){ $("#signup").val('Connecting...');},
        success: function(data){
            alert("ajax ok");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

I don't get error but alert box shows messages (see screenshots below) like

> This site requires javascript to work, please enable javascript in your browser or use a browser with javascript support".

[image: Message Part 2] [image: Message part 1]

Answer (score 0):

You're alerting the entire HTTP response. What format do you want the response in? JSON? If you want to retrieve the response in JSON format you must set the proper HTTP content type header.

Assuming that the only thing getting sent in the output is the ouput of you calling this method.. 
You can change your server side code to this.

```
public function signup()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('value' => 'here is sign up'));
}
```

Now you can access the response via a javascript object.

```
success: function(data){
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(response.value);
}
```

Comment: After applying above changes the ajax call ia success but i am unable to get alert of response. Does my ajax parameters are ok? But When I run this page on web server it run perfectly.

Comment: I found the reason why this happen it is problem of hosting site. I changed my hosting and problem solved.